# using RangeList in Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need help understanding the proper usage of RangeList

I'm trying to identify rows and format them accordingly. As I identify a row, I store it in an array.

However, when I call the formatting of the range, I get an error.

```
function formatCells() {
  var sSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Yearly (Detailed)");

  var sData = sSource.getDataRange().getValues();
  sData.splice(0,4);

  var level1 = new Array();
  var level2 = new Array();
  var level3 = new Array();
  var level4 = new Array();
  var level5 = new Array();
  var level6 = new Array();

  for (var i in sData){
    dLevel1 = sData[i][1];
    dLevel2 = sData[i][2];
    dLevel3 = sData[i][3];
    dLevel4 = sData[i][4];
    dLevel5 = sData[i][5];
    dLevel6 = sData[i][6];

    if (dLevel1!="") level1.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    else if (dLevel2!="") level2.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    else if (dLevel3!="") level3.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    else if (dLevel4!="") level4.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    else if (dLevel5!="") level5.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
    else if (dLevel6!="") level6.push(sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation());
  }

  //dLevel1 = ["A5:O5","A23:O23","A28:O28"];
  //var rangeList1 = sSource.getRangeList(["A5:O5","A23:O23","A28:O28"]).setBackground('#999999');
  var rangeList1 = sSource.getRangeList(dLevel1).setBackground('#999999')
  
}
```

The last 3 lines I experimented. Both the commented lines work but not the last one.

Comment: Please add the textual error message.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- It seems that in your script, `dLevel1` is not A1Notation.
- In your situation, I thought that the A1Notations retrieved by the if statement can be populated to an array.
- When I saw your script, `sSource.getRange(parseInt(i)+5,1,1,sSource.getLastColumn()).getA1Notation()` is the same for `level1` to `level6`. So, I thought that this can be simpler.

When the above points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function formatCells() {
  var sSource = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Yearly (Detailed)");
  var sData = sSource.getDataRange().getValues();
  sData.splice(0, 4);
  var lastColumn = sSource.getLastColumn();
  var rangeList = sData.reduce((ar, r, i) => {
    if (r.splice(1, 6).every(e => e.toString() != "")) ar.push(sSource.getRange(i + 5, 1, 1, lastColumn).getA1Notation());
    return ar;
  }, []);
  sSource.getRangeList(rangeList).setBackground('#999999');
}
```

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [getRangeList(a1Notations)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangelista1notations)

Comment: Thank you for this! My programming skill need upgrading as I am stuck to old school! Thanks for pointing out dLevel1..it's actually not the variable that holds the A1N1 notation. It should have been the variable level1 in the rangelist line.

Comment: @bltbersonda Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your replying and current situation, I cannot understand whether my proposed answer was resolved your issue. Can I ask you about it?